# Trying to deploy my flask web app using lighttpd

Tags: python, lighttpd, fastcgi

I'm trying to deploy my flask web app using lighttpd. I created this `hello.fcgi` file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from hello import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

And python file is `hello.py`

I added these lines at the end of the `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`. I wanted it to be accessible from `http://localhost:7777`.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":7777" {
    fastcgi.server = ("/hello.fcgi" =>
        ((
            "socket" => "/tmp/hello-fcgi.sock",
            "bin-path" => "/var/www/html/py/hello.fcgi",
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "max-procs" => 1
        ))
    )

    alias.url = (
        "/static/" => "/var/www/html/py/static"
    )

    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^(/static($|/.*))$" => "$1",
        "^(/.*)$" => "/hello.fcgi$1"
    )
}
```

I also enabled enable the FastCGI, alias and rewrite modules.
All the files of my web app is located inside `/var/www/html/py/` folder including hello.py , hello.fcgi and the "static" folder.

Then I restarted lighttpd and tried to visit `http://localhost:7777` but my browser says "This site can’t be reached".

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't use lighttpd but have you tried accessing it using `http://127.0.0.1` rather than localhost? because generally, websites use virtual hosts to determine what the website should be accessible on which is different than 'listening' on all interfaces (IP addresses).

Comment: @SimonHayter Just tried `http://127.0.0.1:7777` , stll not working

Comment: @user8481790 check that lighttpd is actually running.  It sounds like lighttpd is not running.  Check the lighttpd error.log.  There might be a syntax error in the config.  Run `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -tt` to have lighttpd test and pre-flight the config (which will report errors to stderr, if errors are encountered).